# Sending 2 different sets of error messages from the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an errors array from some validation that occurs when a user submits a registration form. But separate to the form validation is a check to see if the email address exists or not. ( using express validator)

This is how map over the error messages and send back to the client:

```
 const errorMsg = errors.array().map(err => err.msg);
 return res.status(422).send(errorMsg);
```

Then in react I have

```
    try {
      const response = await register(user);
      console.log(response);
    } catch (ex) {
      if (ex.response) {
        const errors = ex.response.data;
        console.log(errors);
        this.setState({ errors });
      }
    }
```

I am then looping through the array on the client to display the error messages back to the user.

```
  {Array.isArray(this.state.errors) && (
    <div className="alert alert-danger">
      {this.state.errors.map((error, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          {error}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )}
```

All the errors show up except for the email address if it has already been used. The error message only shows up in console but not in the alert.

This is how I send back that error message:

```
  const emailExists = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (emailExists) return res.status(400).send("Email already exists");
```

I think my issue is that the other errors are in an array and the unique email one isn't.

Comment: When do you perform the `emailExists` check? At the same time that you attempt to call `register`? What form of db are you using to determine if the email is already registered?

Comment: Correct, I check that at the same time as submitting the registration form. I am using Mongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of your email valdation, you need to return response object containing `errors` key with value as array of string/s. e.g.

```
const emailExists = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
if (emailExists) return res.status(400).send({ errors: ["Email already exists"] });
```

Comment: Close. Seems it has to be: `if (emailExists) return res.status(400).send(["email exists"]);`